# Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation

Tags: ms-access, delphi, ado

I have a Delphi XE app connecting by ADO to an Access MDB file. The following code gives the error "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation" on opening the query. The field RegDate is an Access Date/Time type. dteTo and dteFrom are TDateTimePicker components. I tried using an ftDate parameter type too but get the same error. What is the trick to get date parameters working with ADO?

```
  with DM.Query2 do
  begin
    Close;
    ParamCheck := True;
    SQL.Text:= 'SELECT Sum((ItemCost * Quantity) + GST + PST + Handling) As Total1'+
                ' FROM Software S INNER JOIN Items I ON (S.SoftwareID = I.Invoice)'+
                ' WHERE RegDate BETWEEN :Date1 AND :Date2';
    if chkPaid.Checked then
      SQL.Text:= SQL.Text+' AND S.Paid = True';
    Parameters.ParamByName('Date1').Value:= dteFrom.Date;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Date1').DataType := ftDateTime;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Date2').Value:= dteTo.Date;
    Parameters.ParamByName('Date2').DataType := ftDateTime;
    Open;
    lblYTD.Caption:= 'YTD: '+FieldByName('Total1').AsString;
    Close;
  end;
```

Comment: What are `dteFrom` and `dteTo`?

Comment: OK using the TDateTimePicker DateTime value instead of Date works.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *Orders* table from *DBDemos.mdb* that ships with Delphi, with the Access 15 (*Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0*) driver, the following works fine. Other than the ConnectionString, everything is done in the code; there are no pre-defined parameters or altered properties on the ADOQuery.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select OrderNo, CustNo, SaleDate, ShipDate ' +
                        'From Orders ' +
                        'Where SaleDate between :Date1 and :Date2 ' +
                        'Order By CustNo, OrderNo';

  // Only for demonstration purposes
  DateTimePicker1.Date := EncodeDate(1988, 8, 1);
  DateTimePicker2.Date := EncodeDate(1988, 8, 31);
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date1').Value := DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Date2').Value := DateTimePicker2.DateTime;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  ShowMessage(Format('Found %d records', [ADOQuery1.RecordCount]));
  ADOQuery1.Close;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not using EncodeDate though I'm using a TDateTimePicker which should have the exact same data type. If I use Now() instead of the TDateTimePicker value it works for me too.

Comment: A DateTimePicker works fine as well; it's just harder to show the contents in text. Editing to demonstrate.